# Suggestion for Weights for Weighted Round Robin

Tags: qos, rfc, dscp

I have looked over the book "End-to-End QoS Network Design" by Tim Szigeti et al. and RFC4594. The RFC proposes 14 Service class:

[image]

I have a switch with simple QoS features. It has 14 egress queues on each port and you can only configure weights in weighted round robin scheduler for these queues. No bandwidth allocation and RSVP  are available.
Is there any standard or suggestion or usual way of setting these weights? I couldn't find any weight suggestion for these queues over the internet.
(My switch has 8 egress queues on each port actually but, there are no standard weights for the 8-queue model either. If I reached weights for the 14-queue model, it's not difficult to remap them into the 8-queue model and recalculating weights)

Update:
Thanks @Marc'netztier'Luethi for his comment, it seems there are 12 service classes in the RFC 4954.

Comment: What's the scale of the weights?

Comment: _odd_ DSCP values (See 3rd column from screenshot) ? That's a novum. The Last bit of DSCP's six binary digits was zero, wherever I encountered it so far  - I wonder how they came up with odd values, then. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services#Commonly_used_DSCP_values . Plus: RFC 4954 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4594) ended up with 12 classes. 14 was probably during the draft phase.

Comment: What you are asking really depends on the traffic profile of your network, and what you want to achieve. QoS is very custom configured for each business. For example our business collected a lot of data on actual traffic flows and calculated how to achieve what we wanted. If you have a lot of small packets, e.g. VoIP, then you need to understand that there will be a lot of protocol overhead compared to larger data packets. If there were a one (or even few) size fits all, then the profile(s) would just be built in. It takes a lot of work to get QoS right.

Comment: @Zac67 Each weight could be between 1 and 127.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi , you are right. There is 12 service classes in the RFC 4954.

Comment: @RonMaupin. All I want is something that shortens this way of getting the right QoS. I mean I want Initial weights to set up a metro ethernet network.... but it seems there is no sample for these weights.

Comment: That is because QoS is _very_ custom. Most people use EF as the lowest latency, but some will use it as the highest-latency, most frequently dropped. You need to determine what percentage of your traffic should be treated the best, what that threatment should be, and should you police beyond your determination. There is nothing to which you can refer that says, "_this is the way it should be_." There is a lot of research to do before you implement QoS.

Comment: Also, based on experience, more than half a dozen classes are overkill. You probably want: LLC (real-time traffic like VoIP and video), control traffic (routing protocols, VoIP control, etc.), custom business traffic, default (most traffic), and low priority traffic (bulk traffic like server backups or other traffic that can monopolize the links).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

14 egress queues seems a bit excessive - most devices I dealt with use 3, 4 (most common), or up to 8 queues. I'd just use four which simplifies things:

1. critical traffic (very low-bandwidth, critical control traffic like OSPF, RIP)
2. real-time applications (low bandwidth traffic like VoIP)
3. normal applications (everything not in 1,2 or 4)
4. low-priority (backup, software distribution)

Since bandwidth requirements are somewhat reciprocal to the desired priorities, simple round-robin with equal scheduling would nearly do the job, only low-priority needs some weighing down. With a linear round-robin weight of 1-127, I'd use 32:32:32:8.

More exact queueing and weighing requires you to know your network flows and their respective importance. This in turn may require a deep insight into the application layer as well. Generally, before fighting with QoS fine tuning for a lengthy period of time you should consider scaling up the network.

Comment: OK! Straightforward approach! Thanks.
But another question: How do you classify something like backup or software distribution traffic? Do these services appley specific DSCP value to their packets or network equipment does this?

Comment: I helped to conceive, deploy and proof a similar concept  for a financial institution with multiple divisions (stock exchange, findata collector/disseminator, card transaction processing, inter bank transaction services, trade clearing etc). We ended up calling the classes _VOICE, CONTROL, BUSINESS_ and _BULK_. Every division's CIO was happy to see their traffic treated as BUSINESS, while being protected from BULK. What we never actually told anyone: Everything (there were 100s of applications) not VOICE, CONTROL, BULK got  DSCP 0 and  ran in the default queues of the various devices. :-)

Comment: Mapping everything into just 4 classes/queues has one advantage: If the goal is to have QoS end-to-end, some lower-end platforms (as commonly seen as  access switches) only have 4 hardware queues. With a 4 classes/queues model, you can avoid too much of device specific queue mapping acrobacy.

Comment: @A.A That's actually a whole new question... You can't take any DSCP values for granted unless you've verified them. On the switches, you can usually map priority classes based on source/destination VLAN, source/destination transport-layer ports, or source/destination IP addresses.